# Visualization of Bivariate Distributions

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, distributions

I know it is perfectly possible to show the bivariate probability distributions in MMA. But my question is can we show each dimension of distribution in 2D dimension while we are showing the 3D plot? The same as here:

[image]

How we can have the 2D histograms in the sides and 3D histogram in between?

Comment: Look up `MarginalDistribution[]`, among other things...

Comment: @0x4A4D with 2D histograms on the sides and 3D histogram in the middle?

Comment: Well, you can use `RandomVariate[]` to generate random variates from your bivariate distribution, yes, then use `Histogram[]` on each component of the variates. I'm seeing no 3D histogram, tho; just a point cloud, an enclosing ellipse, and nothing more.

Comment: The more I stare at this plot, the more unstable it becomes -- it keeps flipping in 3D perspective like a Necker cube http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necker_cube

Comment: In case of 3D histogram important question is: what do You want z-scale to show. Maybe You want different scales for marginal distributions and main 2D distribution, that could be reasonable for clarity of plot.

Comment: @Kuba definitely you can read my mind!!Thanks for saying that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can also try this:

Generate yor data:

```
data = RandomVariate[\[ScriptD] = 
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0.9}, {0.9, 2}}], 10^4];
```

To improve a little bit the final image, you might want to introduce lighting vectors:

```
lightSources = {
 {"Directional", White,Scaled[{1, 0, 1}]}, 
 {"Directional", White,Scaled[{1, .5, 1}]}, 
 {"Directional", White, Scaled[{.5, 0, 1}]}
};
```

Create the 3D histogram

```
G1 = Histogram3D[data, {0.25}, "PDF", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, All}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  Boxed -> False, Lighting -> lightSources]
```

Create the individual histograms

```
G3 = Histogram[Transpose[data][[1]], {-4, 4, .25}, "Probability", 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, ColorData["Rainbow"][height]], 
  Axes -> False]
G4 = Histogram[Transpose[data][[2]], {-4, 4, .25}, "Probability", 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, ColorData["Rainbow"][height]], 
  Axes -> False]
```

Show them all together:

```
G5 = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[G3], 
 Polygon[{{4, 4, 0}, {-4, 4, 0}, {-4, 4, 0.2}, {4, 4, 0.2}},  
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False];
G6 = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[G4], 
 Polygon[{{-4, 4, 0}, {-4, -4, 0}, {-4, -4, 0.2}, {-4, 4, 0.2}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False];
Show[G1, G5, G6]
```

[image]

**EDITED**

If you want a strict 2D representation of the data you can try this:

```
DH = DensityHistogram[data, {-4, 4, .25}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> False];
GraphicsGrid[{{G3,}, {DH, Rotate[G4, -.5 Pi]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

**Don't do it!**

3D plots on a 2D surface are an anti-pattern for data visualization. The perspective mapping taints the free perceptual processing you get from your visual cortex. Angles are no longer what they seem. The 3D histogram makes things even worse by the way foreground bars obscure other bars -- not only is the data poorly represented: some of it is invisible!

For example, @RodLm's answer shows exactly what you asked for, but can you tell the 3D histogram distribution represents an ellipse?

A couple links on 3D chart junk angle,
[infovis-wiki](http://www.infovis-wiki.net/index.php/Chart_Junk#3D_Bar_Chart) [peltiertech](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/the-perils-of-being-in-3d/), and a 2D pic (not from Mathematica).

[image: bivariate normal]

Comment: ...and now, an answer I can get behind with...

Comment: Good point. But who said it is going to be printed. It could be part of interactive cdf. Then there will be no doubts.

Comment: Yes and No!Thanks, you are right if we are going to print it and read the data out of it; but as Kuba said it is just to show interactive PDF or CDF.The main problem is about scaling that Kuba mentioned  before as well.

Comment: @xan You can easily show the elliptical relation between the variables by using the `CountourPlot[]` of your data... You could also use `Plot3D[PDF[\[ScriptD], {x, y}], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]` to see the continuous version of the plot...

Comment: @Kuba, The question didn't mention interactive use either. I assume you are referring to how through interaction one can tilt and rotate a 3D view to see hidden elements and how movement helps reduce the mental translation of 2D to 3D. Even so, there is some cost to requiring the viewer to interrogate the graphic instead of having a graphic that can speak for itself.

Comment: @RodLm, From that Plot3D view, I can see the top is elliptical because of the truncated probability dimension (how do I change the scale?), but I can't tell what's obscured without interacting with the plot, which was my main point on the 3D histogram.

Comment: I do agree with You. I just wanted to show it isn't so bad as one could think.

Comment: @xan as you can easily find from the title, it is about bivariates distributions and the resut has to be in 3D plots.It shows from stochastic point how probability of two random variables could effect each other.The points that you mentioned in the linkes that you refereeing , are easily can be shown in 2D but here the story is different. We have no other way just 3D. Sometimes we have to look at the cases from uncertainties point of view!!!!

Comment: Surely there are many other ways besides 3D to view the interaction. A blended point cloud, a heat map (as shown in RodLm's updated answer), a 2D contour plot, a non-parametric density plot, ...

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to show method of displaying marginal distributions based on `Histogram3D`, it has disadvantages, but also a couple of advantages (concise code, tooltip preserved, etc.)

```
hist[data_, rx_, ry_] :=Show[{
   ListPointPlot3D[{##, 0} & @@@ data],
   Histogram3D[{#1, ry} & @@@ data, {.2}],
   Histogram3D[{-rx, #2} & @@@ data, {.2}, ChartStyle -> Red]},
PlotRange -> {{-rx, rx}, {-7, 7}, All}, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 1}}, 
FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}},Boxed -> False]

data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{1, 2}, .8], 10^3];
hist[data, 4, 7]
```

> [image]

**Update after comments and answers:**

The most **important thing is xan's answer**. I agree with that point but I do not consider Alex's question useless.

The issue discussed in comments was about **z-scale**. Marginal distributions are 1D while real data distribution is 2D. Integrals/bin counting/counts per bin differ for them. So the question is, what do we want to show.

I could set "Count" for each, **z-scale tells the truth** but `Histogram3D` looks a little bit flat:

> [image]

`Histogram/Histogram3D` gives us ability to manage bins/values through `PureFunctions` in place of 2nd and 3rd argument of them *(details in Help)*. We can rescale number of counts:

```
Histogram3D[data, {.2}, Function[{x, y, z}, t z] (*t is scale factor*)
```

**Caution:** z axis now is related to marginal distributions only! What I wanted to show is this functionality.

[image]

At the end I decided that if **we want to focus on shapes** of distributions the best solution is to **normalize each distribution at bin with maximum value of counts**. It can be easily applied with previous functionality with function:

```
Function[{x, y, z}, z/Max@z]
```

[image]

One should keep in mind that normalization factor is different for each distribution.

Comment: nice job with less code.Thank you all cause I am learning a lot.

Comment: About Z scale if we are going to have the "Probability" then it would be alright?Right?

Comment: @Alex No I don't think so. Take a look at simpler case of uniform distrubution. If we divide it on 10x10 bins then each bin will have value 1/100 for "Probability" while marginal distributions would have 1x10 bins -> 1/10 for each, so the scale is different.

Comment: Yes.but look at the Rod Lm response.It shows the probability on the axes.Yours code shows the number of data in histogram not "Probability".Then your case from scale point of view is more complicated.Am I right?

Comment: @Alex z-axis on his plot is related to `Histogram3D`. Marginal distributions fit to it because texture which they are is rescaled to fit the box. Try `, Axes -> True` in G3 and G4 and see the real values. So the plot looks good at the end but it would be hard to name z-axis related to those histograms.

Comment: @Alex I think the last solution is what You need.

Comment: many thanks nice job!!! Well-done.

Answer (score 13):

First you determine the binormal distribution of the data:

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{1, 0}, {2.5, 5}, 0], 10^4];
dataX = data[[All, 1]];
dataY = data[[All, 2]];
dist = EstimatedDistribution[data, 
BinormalDistribution[{Subscript[μ, 1], Subscript[μ, 
2]}, {Subscript[σ, 1], Subscript[σ, 2]}, ρ]]
distX = EstimatedDistribution[dataX, 
NormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
distY = EstimatedDistribution[dataY, 
NormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
```

Then you draw the plots for $x$ and $y$ distribution and the contour plot:

```
x = Show[
Histogram[dataX, 20, "PDF", PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-.005, .25}}, 
Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, AspectRatio -> 1/2],
Plot[PDF[distX, x], {x, -20, 20}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Blue}]]]
y = Show[
Histogram[dataY, 20, "PDF", PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-.005, .25}}, 
Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, AspectRatio -> 1/2],
Plot[PDF[distY, x], {x, -20, 20}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Red}]]]
c = ContourPlot[
PDF[dist, {x, y}] == .00001, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
Epilog -> {PointSize[Small], Point /@ data}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
Frame -> False, ContourStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Green}]]
```

Finally, combine it all together:

```
pp1 = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[x], 
Polygon[{{-20, 20, 0}, {20, 20, 0}, {20, 20, .25}, {-20, 
   20, .25}}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}];
pp2 = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[y], 
Polygon[{{-20, -20, 0}, {-20, 20, 0}, {-20, 
   20, .25}, {-20, -20, .25}}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}];
pp3 = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Texture[c], 
Polygon[{{-20, -20, 0}, {20, -20, 0}, {20, 20, 0}, {-20, 20, 0}}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}];

Graphics3D[{pp1[[1]], pp2[[1]], pp3[[1]]}, 
Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 1}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

The result:
[image: 3d plot]

I'm not sure if MMA can do isometric projections.